# Strange problem in VB6 in generation of executable

Tags: vb6, ado

I there

I have this scenario:

**a)** Notebook :Windows Server 2008 R1, Visual basic 6 with all service pack.

**b)** Desktop : Windows Server 2008 R1 (recently update to sp1, i dunno if it is the guilty), Visual basic 6 with all service pack.

**c)** Client machine (Windows XP)

I created an executable in **a)** and installed it in **c)**. It uses ADO (msado15.dll) and it works fine in **a)** and in **C)**

Then, using the same code, i tried to do the same in **b)** (compiling in **b)** ) and it work in **b)** but it fail in **c)**.   I verified that it is the same code in **a)** and in **b)**

In resume:

A machine

- executable_compiled_in_a.exe  WORKS
- executable_compiled_in_b.exe  WORKS

B machine

- executable_compiled_in_a.exe  WORKS
- executable_compiled_in_b.exe  WORKS

C machine (customer machine)

- executable_compiled_in_a.exe  WORKS
- executable_compiled_in_b.exe  FAIL!

The error message is

> Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface

and is trigged by the line

```
Set Data = New ADODB.Connection
```

So, i don't get it what is the trouble, both uses the same reference but **b)** generated a different executable.

ps: MSDAC_TYP DOES NOT WORK IN XP and it is not a problem of MSDAC because the executable generated in a) works in c).

ps2: i also tried using msado27.tlb and msado28.tlb with the same results.

ps3: my developers machines (a) and b) ) are 64bits, while the customer machine is 32bits.

Thanks.

### Update

The latest service of Windows Server 2008 R1 (and i think the same for Windows 7) update the version of ADO and the executables.   Short story, the latest SP1 is evil and will bring a lot of trouble, at least for ADO and development machines.

msado15.dll without service pack 6.1.7600

msado15.dll with service pack 6.1.**7601**

Comment: MDAC was out-of-band component until XP SP1. That is, later service packs (or version of the OS) have it preinstalled and automatically upgraded through Windows Update. Which means you can no longer *install* it through the redistributable exe.

Comment: i just mentioned mdac as a invalid solution because it is the generic solution, even when it is only appliable only for pre-windows xp machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [kb983246](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983246) on your client's machines. Another workaround is to use the ADO old type library but it have the issue described in kb983246 on 64bit machines.

Comment: Thanks but sadly is easiest to uninstall sp1 rather to update all clients.

Answer (score 0):

The typelibs all reference msado15.dll, which itself contains the typelib for the MDAC/WDAC version it is part of.  The typelibs each describe a different ADO interface version.

Generally you should use the newest version your application requires, and no newer.  This gives you broadest compatibility.  For a lot of applications this means 2.5, though later SQL Server support may require 2.7 or 2.8 and there are a few things you can do in 2.6 that are not in 2.5.

Don't just blindly use the newest interface available.

However few XP machines in the wild won't have 2.8 installed.  That's probably why MDAC_TYP "won't work" for you.

I can only guess that somebody has trashed the DAC software stack on one or both of your Server 2008 machines.  Probably by installing crapware with UAC disabled, bypassing WRP.  Or worse yet by using the built-in admin account of the machine.

Otherwise a program compiled against "msado15.dll" (i.e. ADO 6.x) on either of them would not work on an XP machine at all.

Just the fact that you're running Server 2008 as a desktop OS sets off alarm bells here.

Comment: I there:   I tried with older mdac with the same resultant.  Anyways, as a developer, i must not be afraid to work without UAC or directly in a windows server machine, in fact, my reason to work directly in windows server is because you are ensure that you software will work fine in windows server (IIS), even more every developer that work for IIS project must do the same (specially for Sharepoint).   In any case, MDAC/WDAC works in every machine, it can connect to sql and do all the task, just the combination to compile in a specific machine and to use in another does not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Copy masado28.tlb from pre-SP1 machine on your developer machine with SP1 to some folder(For example to %CommonProgramFiles%\System\ado\PRESP1). Open regedit with Adminstrative privilegies, find all values msado28.tlb and replace all values "%CommonProgramFiles%\System\ado\msado28.tlb" with "%CommonProgramFiles%\System\ado\PRESP1\msado28.tlb". Before change set Permission "Full Access" for Administrators on keys. In VB Project references use "Microsoft ActiveX DataObjects 2.8 Library", on Location: you will see C:\Program Files(x86)\Common Files\System\ado\PRESP1\msado28.tlb. Now you may recompile you VB Application and your executeable file must run without errors on all mashines.